# Button listener inside a list producing unexpected results

Tags: java, android, listview

```
public class CustomerProductAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context ccon;
ImageView cprdctimg;

LayoutInflater cprdctinflater;
View cprdctview;
TextView cprdctname,cprdctdesc,cprdctprice,cprdctquant,cpquantity;
ArrayList<Product> cproduct;
Product currentproduct;
Button cpincq,cpdecq;
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return cproduct.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return cproduct.get(i).getPname();
}

public CustomerProductAdapter(Context con,ArrayList<Product> product) {
    this.cproduct=product;
    this.ccon = con;
    cprdctinflater=LayoutInflater.from(con);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, final ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    cprdctview=cprdctinflater.inflate(R.layout.cplist,null);
    cpincq=cprdctview.findViewById(R.id.cpincq);
    cpquantity=cprdctview.findViewById(R.id.cpquantity);
    cpdecq=cprdctview.findViewById(R.id.cpdecq);
    cprdctname=cprdctview.findViewById(R.id.cpname);
    cprdctdesc=cprdctview.findViewById(R.id.cpdesc);
    cprdctimg=cprdctview.findViewById(R.id.cppic);
    cprdctprice=cprdctview.findViewById(R.id.cpprice);
    cprdctquant=cprdctview.findViewById(R.id.cpquant);

    currentproduct=cproduct.get(i);
    cprdctimg.setImageResource(cproduct.get(i).getPimage());
    cprdctname.append(cproduct.get(i).getPname().toString());
    cprdctdesc.append(cproduct.get(i).getPdesc().toString());
    cprdctprice.append(cproduct.get(i).getPprice().toString());
    cprdctquant.append(cproduct.get(i).getPquant());

    cpincq.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            currentproduct.inccustomerquantity();
            if(currentproduct.getcustomerquantity()>Integer.parseInt(currentproduct.getPquant()))
            {
                Toast.makeText(viewGroup.getContext(), "You cannot order more than stock", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                currentproduct.deccustomerquantity();
            }
            else {
                cpquantity.setText("" + currentproduct.getcustomerquantity());
            }
        }
    });
    cpdecq.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(currentproduct.deccustomerquantity()) {
                cpquantity.setText("" + currentproduct.getcustomerquantity());
            }
        }
    });

    return cprdctview;
}
}
```

Here, if I increase the quantity of one product in the list, the corresponding TextView isn't changing.Instead some other TextView in a different list item is changed. As you can see in the image,the quantity of grapes changes when I click "+" symbol in banana item. Please help me to fix this error so that the change is made only to the appropriate textview.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you click a button, you need to change the model in the list, not the UI. After that, update the desired position of the adapter. I suggest you look at the ViewHolder template.

Comment: I have updated the model as you have said.See the line `currentproduct.inccustomerquantity();` .What do you mean by updating the desired position of the adapter.I have updated the model.But how to update the adapter.Can you give an example please.

Answer (score 0):

GetView() is called everytime when creates a row. Therefore your global/instance variables (**currentproduct, cprdctname, cprdctdesc...**), are always refer to the last created row (when scroll up, the bottom one; when scroll down, the top one). You may save item row position as **Tag** to the buttons and update the corresponding item in data list. Then call adapter to redraw all the rows by notifyDataSetChanged().

Try this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, final ViewGroup viewGroup) {
cprdctview=cprdctinflater.inflate(R.layout.cplist,null);
cpincq=cprdctview.findViewById(R.id.cpincq);
cpquantity=cprdctview.findViewById(R.id.cpquantity);
cpdecq=cprdctview.findViewById(R.id.cpdecq);
cprdctname=cprdctview.findViewById(R.id.cpname);
cprdctdesc=cprdctview.findViewById(R.id.cpdesc);
cprdctimg=cprdctview.findViewById(R.id.cppic);
cprdctprice=cprdctview.findViewById(R.id.cpprice);
cprdctquant=cprdctview.findViewById(R.id.cpquant);

currentproduct=cproduct.get(i);
cprdctimg.setImageResource(cproduct.get(i).getPimage());
cprdctname.append(cproduct.get(i).getPname().toString());
cprdctdesc.append(cproduct.get(i).getPdesc().toString());
cprdctprice.append(cproduct.get(i).getPprice().toString());
cprdctquant.append(cproduct.get(i).getPquant());

cpincq.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        currentproduct = cproduct.get((int)view.getTag()); // Get item for the clicked position
        currentproduct.inccustomerquantity();
        if(currentproduct.getcustomerquantity()>Integer.parseInt(currentproduct.getPquant()))
        {
            Toast.makeText(viewGroup.getContext(), "You cannot order more than stock", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            currentproduct.deccustomerquantity();
        }
        else {
            //cpquantity.setText("" + currentproduct.getcustomerquantity());
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
});
cpdecq.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        currentproduct = cproduct.get((int)view.getTag()); // Get item for the clicked position
        if(currentproduct.deccustomerquantity()) {
            //cpquantity.setText("" + currentproduct.getcustomerquantity());
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
});

// Save the current position as Tag to the buttons
cpincq.setTag(i);
cpdecq.setTag(i);

return cprdctview;
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

As per android official documentation , do not use position as it  gets reused . Using getAdapterPosition() is recommended.  So in your code instead of  listOfItems.get(i) use listOfItems(getAdapterPosition())